# Making a POST and GET in the same sketch

Tags: android, arduino

:D Hi! I'm in the middle of a nice project. Is about automation of a water pump for town's aqueduct. So I chose Arduino for the task. I'm planning to communicate an Android App with Arduino through internet connection. I already made the API and web server part, and also de App (and in the app now I'm able to see my DB data). Now, I'm on the Arduino-Ethernet shield's side. I tested the GET method, and it work pretty well, also the POST method. But, when I try to mix them, they just stopped working. I did some (extensive) search on different tutorials and forums, and read "making a client for GET and another for the PUT", and got the PUT method working again (now I can see my webServer response), but the GET method is not working :(. Could you give me some advice about how to mix them? Or any idea? Thanks!
This is the mixed code:

```html
/*
   Web client sketch for IDE v1.0.1 and w5100/w5200
   Uses POST method.
   Posted November 2012 by SurferTim
*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet2.h>

double lecturasensor1 =20.40;
double lecturasensor2 =20.60;
char var1[6];
char var2[6];
String a ;
String b ;

int id = 1;

byte mac[] = {  
  0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x10, 0x5B, 0x2B };

//Change to your server domain
char serverName[] = "asada-florencia.herokuapp.com";

// change to your server's port
int serverPort = 80;

// change to the page on that server
char pageName[] = "/lecturas";

EthernetClient clientGET;
EthernetClient clientPOST;
IPAddress ip(172, 24, 46, 94);
int totalCount = 0;
// insure params is big enough to hold your variables
char params[100];

// set this to the number of milliseconds delay
// this is 30 seconds
#define delayMillis 8000UL

unsigned long thisMillis = 0;
unsigned long lastMillis = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // disable SD SPI no vamos a usar SD
  //pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  //digitalWrite(4,HIGH);

    if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("connecting...");

}

void loop()
{
//Pirmero el GET (por prioridad)
  if (clientGET.connect(serverName, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    clientGET.println("GET /lecturas HTTP/1.1");
    clientGET.println("Host: asada-florencia.herokuapp.com");
    clientGET.println("Connection: close");
    clientGET.println();
  }
  else {
    // kf you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }

  if (clientGET.available()) {
    char c = clientGET.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!clientGET.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    clientGET.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while (true);
  }
/*
 * final GET
 * 
------------------------------------------
 *
 * Ahora el POST después de un tiempo
 */
 delay(3000);

  thisMillis = millis();

  if(thisMillis - lastMillis > delayMillis)
  {
    lastMillis = thisMillis;

    a = dtostrf(lecturasensor1, 4 , 4 , var1);
    b = dtostrf(lecturasensor2, 4 , 4 , var2);
    
    String jsonString = "{\"valor\" : ";
    jsonString += a;
    jsonString +=" , \"valor2\" : ";
    jsonString += b;
    jsonString +="\"}";

    clientPOST.print(jsonString);
    Serial.print(jsonString);
      
    if(!postPage(serverName,serverPort,pageName,params)) Serial.print(F("Fail "));
    else Serial.print(F("Pass "));
    totalCount++;
    Serial.println(totalCount,DEC);
  }    
}

byte postPage(char* domainBuffer,int thisPort,char* page,char* thisData)
{
  int inChar;
  char outBuf[64];

  Serial.print(F("connecting..."));

  if(clientPOST.connect(domainBuffer,thisPort) == 1)
  {
    Serial.println(F("connected"));

    // send the header
    sprintf(outBuf,"POST %s HTTP/1.1",page);
    clientPOST.println(outBuf);
    sprintf(outBuf,"Host: %s",domainBuffer);
    clientPOST.println(outBuf);
    clientPOST.println(F("Connection: close\r\nContent-Type: application/json"));
    sprintf(outBuf,"Content-Length: %u\r\n",strlen(thisData)); //thisData solo toma en cuenta la medida del header por que el server lo necesita
    clientPOST.println(outBuf);

    // buscar cómo realizar el POST HTTP (sintaxis)-->thisData esta como puntero que contiene las variables a mostrar en el "body"
    //esto que sigue es el envio de datos thisData
    clientPOST.print(thisData);
    Serial.println("Datos enviados");
    Serial.println(thisData);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println(F("failed"));
    return 0;
  }

  int connectLoop = 0;

  while(clientPOST.connected())
  {
    while(clientPOST.available())
    {
      inChar = clientPOST.read();
      Serial.write(inChar);
      connectLoop = 0;
    }

    delay(1);
    connectLoop++;
    if(connectLoop > 10000)
    {
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println(F("Timeout"));
      clientPOST.stop();
    }
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("disconnecting."));
  clientPOST.stop();
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: `if (clientGET.connect(serverName, 80))`. So the Arduino is making GET or POST requests to some webserver? Where does Android come in play? What dit you try to mix in GET and POST? You talked about it as if you were receiving those requests. Please add all info to your post not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it! :D It was all in the GET header, just used the clientPOST.println() for each part of the header. Thank you!!

```html
// Header del GET
    clientPOST.println("GET /yourendpoint HTTP/1.1");
    clientPOST.println("Host: yourhost.com");
    clientPOST.println("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
    clientPOST.println("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1");
    clientPOST.println("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36");
    clientPOST.println("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch");
    clientPOST.println("Accept-Language: en-US,en");
    clientPOST.println();
```

Thank you!